# curl request not working from Jenkins

Tags: curl, jenkins

So I'm stuck with something basic. I'm trying to trigger a Jenkins job from a remote Jenkins instance with this curl command.

```
curl -v -X POST https://myUsername:myAPIToken@myJenkins.com:8080/job/myJob/buildWithParameters?param=value --data token=myToken
```

This command works absolutely fine and triggers the remote Jenkins job successfully when tried from the terminal, but it gives an error `curl: (35) gnutls_handshake() failed: An unexpected TLS packet was received.` when tried through another Jenkins job on another Jenkins instance (Execute shell).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the correct command which worked for me.

`curl -iv -u myJenkinsUsername:myJenkinsApiToken "https://myJenkins.com:443/job/myRemoteJob/buildWithParameters?param=value"`

The option `-i` includes protocol headers in the request and apparently, I was mentioning the wrong port number (8080) earlier.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use SSL just try `-k` flag. From curl manual:

> -k, --insecure
>                 (SSL) This option explicitly allows curl to  perform  "insecure"
>                 SSL connections and transfers. All SSL connections are attempted
>                 to be made secure by using the CA certificate  bundle  installed
>                 by  default.  This  makes  all connections considered "insecure"
>                 fail unless -k, --insecure is used.

Comment: Even after using the --insecure flag (like this: `curl -v -X POST https://myUsername:myAPIToken@myJenkins.com:8080/job/myJob/buildWithParameters?param=value --data token=myToken --insecure`), it does not seem to work for me. I get the same error: `gnutls_handshake() failed: An unexpected TLS packet was received.`

Comment: And how about `-v`? There in no more information? It's look like your server have problem with https. Can You `curl` simple GET or checkout another website? Maybe it's network layer problem.

Comment: Here's the verbose output:

* Connected to myJenkins.com port 8080 (#0)
* found 148 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 596 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* gnutls_handshake() failed: An unexpected TLS packet was received.

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) gnutls_handshake() failed: An unexpected TLS packet was received.

Comment: `gnutls-cli -p 8080  myJenkins.com` ?

Comment: I'm facing a few issues installing the `gnutls-cli`. Any other ways to check more in this issue?

Comment: It Isn't a frequent problem. Do you have installed `gnutls-bin` on machine ?

Comment: Installed `gnutls-bin` with `sudo apt-get install gnutls-bin`. Here's the output of `gnutls-cli`:

Processed 148 CA certificate(s).
Resolving 'myJenkins.com'...
Cannot resolve myJenkins.com:8080: Name or service not known

Comment: Now you host can't revolved Jenkins address. Add it to `/etc/hosts`, or change for IP.

Comment: Checked using the public IP of the server: gnutls-cli -p 8080 <IP_address>

Here's the output:

Processed 148 CA certificate(s).
Resolving '<IP_address>'...
Connecting to '<IP_address>:8080'...
|<1>| Received record packet of unknown type 72
*** Fatal error: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
*** Handshake has failed
GnuTLS error: An unexpected TLS packet was received.